# Optional nested injection of Spring Services

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Given an interface `IService`, and 3 implementations of it: `ServiceA`, `ServiceALogger` and `ServiceAMetrics`.

`ServiceALogger` and `ServiceAMetrics` are wrappers of the `ServiceA` and will be instantiated optionally. Moreover there is a combination where `ServiceAMetrics` and `ServiceALogger` both instantiated.

I know how to implement it using `@Configuration` and `@Bean` method, but is it possible to implement using class annotations (`@Primary`, `@Order`...)?

Here is a snippet to demonstrate a concept:

```
package com.foo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

interface IService {
    void foo();
}

class LoggerCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        return false;
    }
}

class MetricsCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        return false;
    }
}

@Service
class ServiceA implements IService {

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("I'm foo");
    }
}

@Service
@Conditional(LoggerCondition.class)
class ServiceALogger implements IService {
    private final IService service;

    public ServiceALogger(IService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("print some logs");
        service.foo();
    }
}

@Service
@Conditional(MetricsCondition.class)
class ServiceAMetrics implements IService {
    private final IService service;

    public ServiceAMetrics(IService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("send some metrics");
        service.foo();
    }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.foo")
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(Main.class);
        ctx.refresh();

        IService bean = ctx.getBean(IService.class);
        bean.foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I found a possible solution. It's not an elegant one, but it works.

I use `@Priority` annotations to determine what bean should be injected when there are several instances of them. And `@Qualifier` to break a circular dependency between `ServiceAMetrics` and `ServiceALogger`.

```
package com.foo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import java.util.List;

interface IService {
    void foo();
}

class LoggerCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        return true;
    }
}

class MetricsCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        return true;
    }
}

@Service
@Qualifier("main")
@Priority(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
class ServiceA implements IService {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("I'm foo");
    }
}

@Service
@Conditional(LoggerCondition.class)
@Priority(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)
class ServiceALogger implements IService {
    private final IService service;

    // using this @Qualifier prevents circular dependency
    public ServiceALogger(@Qualifier("main") IService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("print some logs");
        service.foo();
    }
}

@Service
@Conditional(MetricsCondition.class)
@Priority(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2)
class ServiceAMetrics implements IService {
    private final IService service;

    public ServiceAMetrics(IService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("send some metrics");
        service.foo();
    }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.foo")
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(Main.class);
        ctx.refresh();

        IService bean = ctx.getBean(IService.class);
        bean.foo();
    }
}
```